# I need help updating Ubuntu 11.04... so many problems

Tags: installation, boot, 11.04, software-center

This computer was originally Windows Vista, but Boot manager went missing and couldn't boot up.

A friend of mine gave me a compact disk with Linux 11.04, and replaced Vista. However, I am unable to login in any way other than in `Safe Mode`, or `Classic: No Effects`. I realize you can go into Update Manager and update it from there, but I need to download it from the Ubuntu software Center, which freezes upon launch. There was one time where I was able to search something in the software center, and turns out I have no sources to download anything. 700 some packages are broken, that may be a good connection, but I'll do the repair process and it'll say it fixed everything, when it did virtually nothing.

I downloaded the .iso for the newer Ubuntu, and made a bootable flashdrive, and using <kbd>F12</kbd> to boot from the memory stick, it would start to work. Whatever option I chose from there (run Ubuntu from usb, install Ubuntu on a hard disk, etc) it would blast through some terminal stuff, then stop at when it says:

```
,locks=none
```

or under that it stops at

```
[   0.288973] PnPBIOS: PnP BIOS version 1.0, entry 0xf0000:0x9afd, dseg 0x400
```

So, uh, are there any other methods of installing Ubuntu on a broken Ubuntu? Should I just buy a new computer? I'm stuck and lost and don't know what to do.

Comment: "[b]ut I need to download it from the Ubuntu software Center, which freezes upon launch." You don't have the Update Manager? You can use `do-release-upgrade` in the Terminal. Your release is unsupported, and the only release you can upgrade to directly (11.10) is also unsupported, so you'll have to go 11.04 -> 11.10 -> 12.04 LTS (which is supported). And you'll need to switch to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` download servers (for example, by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`. See [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815) (Maybe a duplicate.)

Comment: Or save yourself of many headaches and just do a fresh install **(of course, always doing a backup of your important data)**